# suspend taxonomy term in drupal

Tags: drupal, admin, cck, drupal-taxonomy

People submit a taxonomy terms to my site and i want to able to do "publish"/unpublish to the real vocabulary, is there a module that do it ? like term status = suspend?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Term status](http://drupal.org/project/termstatus) would suit your needs?

It is module for Drupal 7, for Drupal 6 only this [experimental code](http://drupal.org/sandbox/asimfastian/1179898) exists.

Answer (score -1):

One way to easily reorder/manager taxonomy is [taxonomy_manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module. You should have a look on it.

Comment: I think that there is no way to unpublish/publish a term with taxonomy manager. or I am wrong?